# How to replace space with "%20" in javascript "for" statement?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have this script from a google blog. Into `for` statement I want to add a part of code that replace space with "%20". My problem is that I can't imagine the syntax. Any idea? Thank you!

```
//<![CDATA[

    function showLabels(json){
        var label = json.feed.category;
        document.write('<div id="filters" class="portfolioSection">');
        document.write('<div>');
        document.write('<ul>');

        document.write('<li class="title">LABELS:</li>');
        document.write('<li><a class="current" href="#Blog1" data-filter="*">All</a></li>');
        document.write('<li><a class="no_labels" href="#Blog1" data-filter=".no-labels">no labels</a></li>');

        for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++){
            document.write('<li><a href="#Blog1" data-filter=".' + label[i].term + '">' + label[i].term + '</a></li>');
        }

        document.write('<span class="show_ico icon-remove"/>');
        document.write('</ul>');
        document.write('</div>');
        document.write('</div>');
    }   

    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="' + HomePageUrl + '/feeds/posts/summary?max-results=0&alt=json-in-script&callback=showLabels"><\/scr' + 'ipt>');
//]]>
```

**Edited:** Spaces located in `label[i].term` into `for` statement. It contains label's name from a google blog. For example label can be `Test Label`. With space doesn't work when someone click on it cause url looks like this `http://www.sitename.net/search/label/Test Label`. What I want to do is to replace the space so it will look like this `http://www.sitename.net/search/label/Test%20Label`.

Comment: where the space exists? is it in label[i].term or HomePageUrl or ..?

Comment: Can you show you i/p and o/p sample, sorry I'm confused a bit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @AmrElgarhy & Sudhansu Choudhary: I added additional info, please take a look now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not:

```
string.replace(/ /g, '%20')
```

Edited to fix.

Comment: This will only replace the first space

Comment: Tom you're right, my bad! Fixed.

Comment: @JBux: And how can I put this in my `for` statement?

Comment: label[i].term.replace(/ /g, '%20') where you have just label[i].term

Answer (score 6):

I literally just did this yesterday. If you want to replace spaces, the easiest way is:

```
var sentence = "This is a sentence"
sentence.split(" ").join("%20");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I put this in my `for` statement?

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "";
// label is the string you want to modify
for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
      if (label.charAt(i) == ' ') {
           str += "%20";
      } else {
           str += label.charAt(i);
      }
}
```

Comment: could anybody explain the downvotes?

Comment: I haven't down voted, but I imagine people would be because this seems a very slow way to go about the problem. It's not a wrong answer, just not the best one.

Comment: @JBux, he wanted to use a "`for` statement"...

Comment: I think he meant he wanted the solution to be inside the `for` statement inside his posted code.